# How do you use fit_params for RandomizedSearch with VotingClassifier in Sklearn?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, grid-search

Hi I'm trying to use fit_params (for sample_weight on GradientBoostingClassifier) for RandomizedSearch with VotingClassifier in Sklearn since the dataset is unbalanced. Could someone give me advice and possibly code sample?

My current-not-working code is below:

```
random_search = RandomizedSearchCV(my_votingClassifier, param_distributions=param_dist,
                                   n_iter=n_iter_search, n_jobs=-1, fit_params={'sample_weight':y_np_array})
```

Error:

```
TypeError: fit() got an unexpected keyword argument 'sample_weight'
```

Comment: I'm on it, but found nothing. Basically you are saying in `fit_params` the parameters that should be used by the `fit` method of the classifier. But in your case the classifier is a `VotingClassifier` instance which has no `sample_weight` param. So, basically I'm afraid you cannot do what you pretend here. But still searching if there is a hack to pass another level to the real classifier that admits that `sample_weight` parameter.

Comment: I mean, right now you have something like this: `RandomizedSearchCV --> VotingClassifier(sample_weight) --> EnsembleOfClassifiers` but you want to make this param go to the classifiers you are gonna use to vote, something like this:  `RandomizedSearchCV --> VotingClassifier --> EnsembleOfClassifiers(sample_weight)`. Hopefully this clarifies the `keyword` error but I'm not able to find a solution, don't even know if it is possible.

Comment: Thanks a lot Guiem :) Yeah I'm still googling but can't find a solution yet.. Maybe it's not possible with current version. I should probably ask directly to Github issues.

Comment: sorry, couldn't find anything :( Gonna star you question so I can follow its progress. Good luck!

Comment: No you don't need to sorry :) Yep, I'll update if I find out the solution!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Taking into account that there doesn't seem to be a direct way to pass `sample_weight` parameter through the `VotingClassifier` I came across this little "hack":

Override the `fit` method of the classifiers at the bottom. For example, if you are using a `DecisionTreeClassifier` you could override its `fit` method by passing through the desired `sample_weight` parameter.

```
class MyDecisionTreeClassifier(DecisionTreeClassifier):
    def fit(self, X , y = None):
        return super(DecisionTreeClassifier, self).fit(X,y,sample_weight=y)
```

Now in your ensemble of classifiers in your `VotingClassifier` you can use your own `MyDecisionTreeClassifier`.

Full working example:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import VotingClassifier
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.grid_search import RandomizedSearchCV

X = np.array([[-1, -1], [-2, -1], [-3, -2], [1, 1], [2, 1], [3, 2]])
y = np.array([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2])

class MyDecisionTreeClassifier(DecisionTreeClassifier):
    def fit(self, X , y = None):
        return super(DecisionTreeClassifier, self).fit(X,y,sample_weight=y)

clf1 = MyDecisionTreeClassifier()
clf2 = RandomForestClassifier() 
params = {'dt__max_depth': [5, 10],'dt__max_features':[1,2]} 
eclf = VotingClassifier(estimators=[('dt', clf1), ('rf', clf2)], voting='hard')
random_search = RandomizedSearchCV(eclf, param_distributions=params,n_iter=4)
random_search.fit(X, y)
print(random_search.grid_scores_)
print(random_search.best_score_)
```

Comment: I know you are not using a DecisionTreeClassifier, but a GradientBoostingClassifier. I just reused my example from my previous answer ;) But if it accepts the `sample_weight` param you only need to change the tree by your class. I know it's not the prettiest way to do it, but as I've been struggling for a while with your question and it came up to my mind I'm just sharing in case it is of use to you. Cheers!

Comment: Wow, this is amazing :D It worked on my model with a dataset. I like the hack a lot. Thanks so much for helping me out, Guiem.

Comment: Actually, I'm getting an error "ValueError: y contains non binary labels." with my dataset.. Do you happen to have any idea? I checked the labels and they are 0s and 1s. 
The difference is that I used train_test_split to make X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test. So random_search.fit(X_train, y_train) instead of X and y.

Comment: No idea, sir. Could you print a piece of your 'y'? Btw, randomsearch performs a Cross Validation so conceptually there is no need to split train and test data. Unless, of course, you want to keep a portion of your data 'pure', without being used in any possible training (even if that's a pre-search for the best params).

Comment: Thanks again! Some piece of y is [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0. 0.  0.] and it's np array. You are right. But it still doesn't work with my full y either :(